Error when updating linux (launchpad/appimagelauncher)
I tried updating my Ubuntu and I started getting this error. I think I had some issues when installing launchpad but it works how its going at the moment. Iv tried looking at other similar issues but nothing has worked.
Here is what i get when i try update
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease        
Get:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease [89.7 kB]
Hit:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease         
Ign:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/appimagelauncher-team/stable/ubuntu noble InRelease
Err:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/appimagelauncher-team/stable/ubuntu noble Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::81 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/appimagelauncher-team/stable/ubuntu noble Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.```

Thank you for any help


The repository of the stable release accept only the following codenames (see here):
devel
disco
eoan
focal
groovy
hirsute
impish
jammy
kinetic

On Ubuntu Noble, you need to use the daily build (testing):
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:appimagelauncher-team/daily
sudo apt update
sudo apt install appimagelauncher 


I get thrown the error: E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/appimagelauncher-team/stable/ubuntu noble Release' does not have a Release file.
